# Android ListViewe Filtration for loading large amount of data from server

Tags: java, android

i am loading data from server to hashmap array and showing the data into listView.
As the data is big with images, i want to apply filter or pagination on listview to load only 10-15 item and when i click on load more or scroll down then next data appear in bottom of listView like facebook does.
I am using Glide API for loading images and using custome Adapter for setting data into listView.

```
    final String propertyID = contactList.get(position).get("property_id").toString();
   final String propertyTitle = contactList.get(position).get("property_title").toString();
   final String price = contactList.get(position).get("price").toString();
    String country = contactList.get(position).get("country").toString();
    String city = contactList.get(position).get("city").toString();
    String location = contactList.get(position).get("location").toString();
   final String landArea = contactList.get(position).get("landArea").toString();
   final String contact = contactList.get(position).get("phone").toString();
    String propertyType = contactList.get(position).get("property_type").toString();
    String propertystatus =  contactList.get(position).get("status").toString();
    String description = contactList.get(position).get("property_description").toString();
    String rooms = contactList.get(position).get("rooms").toString();
    String bathrooms = contactList.get(position).get("bathrooms").toString();
    String floors = contactList.get(position).get("floors").toString();
    String status_property = contactList.get(position).get("status_property").toString();
    String dealer_email = contactList.get(position).get("dealer_email").toString();



    tv_property_id.setText(propertyID);
    tv_propertyTitle.setText(propertyTitle);
    tv_price.setText(price);
    tv_country.setText(country);
    tv_propertyCity.setText(city);
    tv_propertyPhone.setText(contact);
    tv_propertyPropertyLandArea.setText(landArea);
    tv_protperty_type.setText(propertyType);
    tv_protperty_status.setText(propertystatus);
    tv_protperty_description.setText(description);
    tv_propertyLocation.setText(location);

    tv_propertyEmail.setText(dealer_email);

    tv_property_rooms.setText(rooms);
    tv_property_bathrooms.setText(bathrooms);
    tv_property_floors.setText(floors);
    tv_property_status_prpoperty.setText(status_property);

    //imageLoader.DisplayImage(contactList.get(position).get("imageurl"), image);

    Glide.with(activity)
            .load(contactList.get(position).get("imageurl"))
            .placeholder(R.drawable.default_image)
            //.error(R.drawable.)
            .override(200, 200)
            .centerCrop()
            .into(image);
```

and Adapter code is
 HashMap contact = new HashMap<>();

```
                    contact.put("property_id", property_id);
                    contact.put("imageurl", imageURL);
                    contact.put("property_title", property_title);
                    contact.put("price", price);
                    contact.put("landArea", landArea);
                    contact.put("country", country);
                    contact.put("city", city);
                    contact.put("phone", phone);
                    contact.put("property_type", propertyType);
                    contact.put("status", propertystatus);
                    contact.put("property_description", description);
                    contact.put("location", propertyLocation);

                    contact.put("dealer_email", dealer_email);

                    contact.put("rooms", rooms);
                    contact.put("bathrooms", bathrooms);
                    contact.put("floors", floors);
                    contact.put("status_property", status_property);

                    contactList.add(contact);

                    Log.e("TAG", "Image URL: " + imageURL);


                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

            }

        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please Check your Internet Connection!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }

        adapter=new DataAdapter(ShowProperties.this, contactList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

How does i apply filtration that it loading only 10, after scrolling down it load more ten and so on.

Answer (score 0):

There are solutions ready for that case. I suggest you use one of working examples.
Here is one:

[Endless Scrolling with AdapterViews and RecyclerView](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView)

Comment: Thanks i will test it